# ¿Como lograr que un web view que carga una pagina de login recuerde las credenciales introducidas?

Tags: android

Lo que quiero que me enseñen no es mas que lo que hacen casi todos los navegadores como el firefox que cuando entras a facebook y te logueas te saca un cartel diciendo desea guardar en nombre de usuario y la contraseña.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_web);

    //Activar Flecha ir atras
    getSupportActionBar().setDefaultDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);

    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    // Ajustamos la vista para que no se vea demasiado grande
    webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);

    // habilitamos el zoom
    webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view, final SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error) {
            String message = "SSL Certificate error.";
            switch (error.getPrimaryError()) {
                case SslError.SSL_UNTRUSTED:
                    message = "The certificate authority is not trusted.";
                    break;
                case SslError.SSL_EXPIRED:
                    message = "The certificate has expired.";
                    break;
                case SslError.SSL_IDMISMATCH:
                    message = "The certificate Hostname mismatch.";
                    break;
                case SslError.SSL_NOTYETVALID:
                    message = "The certificate is not yet valid.";
                    break;
            }
            message += "\"SSL Certificate Error\" Do you want to continue anyway?.. YES";

            handler.proceed();
        }
    });

    webView.loadUrl("http://correo.ucf.edu.cu/owa");

    webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient()
    {
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress)
        {
            progressBar.setProgress(0);
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            progressBar.setProgress(progress*1000);
            progressBar.incrementProgressBy(progress);
            if(progress == 100)
            {
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Cualquier ayuda es agradecida.

Comment: y cual es el código para saber que estas realizando. ¿Como introduces las credenciales?

Comment: @Jorgesys Como dije es una pagina web los credenciales los introduces como mismo lo haces en un navegador... Lo que quiero saber es como capturarlos cuando el usuario inicia la sesion

Comment: Si estás dentro de un form y tienes boton submit, el navegador lo maneja solo, de todos modos puedes mirar éste hilo:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2382329/how-can-i-get-browser-to-prompt-to-save-password

Comment: Revise lo que me diste pero siendote sincero no entendi nada de eso, disculpame no llevo mucho tiempo programando en android mi funcion de webView es bastante sencilla lo unico que quiero agregarle eso. Entendi mas menos lo que hay que hacer pero no se como hacerlo, ni se tampoco como detectar los input de una pagina web

Comment: comparte tu código para poder entender el contexto